# Strange behavior from to_datetime()

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, string-to-datetime

I have really been having a tough time here.

My DataFrame looks like this

```
     Purchase_Date     Customer_ID  Gender  
0   2012-12-18 00:00:00   7223        F 
1   2012-12-20 00:00:00   7841        M     
2   2012-12-21 00:00:00   8374        F
```

My goal is to change the "Purchase Date" column from string to datetime object so that I can run a cohort analysis by applying this function to it:

```
      def get_month(x): return dt.datetime(x.year, x.month, 1)
      data['InvoiceMonth'] = data['Purchase_Date'].apply(get_month)
      grouping = data.groupby('Customer_ID')['InvoiceMonth']
      data['CohortMonth'] = grouping.transform('min')
```

the function returns error:  **'str' object has no attribute 'year'**
I have tried the following functions and played with all arguments (dayfirst, yearfirst...)

```
data["Purchase_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Purchase_Date"])
pd.to_datetime()
datetime.datetime.strptime()
```

I keep getting **ValueError: day is out of range for month**

Please help out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you were almost there:

```py
data["Purchase_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Purchase_Date"])
data['InvoiceMonth'] = data["Purchase_Date"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-01")
```

(Outputs month in `object` format - you can convert it to `datetime` by adding `pd.to_datetime(...)`)

Or alternatively - using your approach:

```py
data["Purchase_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Purchase_Date"])

import datetime as dt

def get_month(x): return dt.datetime(x.year, x.month, 1)

data['InvoiceMonth'] = data["Purchase_Date"].apply(get_month)
```

(Outputs month as `datetime`)

Both will return, although I would highly recommend the first option:

```py
  Purchase_Date  Customer_ID Gender InvoiceMonth
0    2012-12-18         7223      F   2012-12-01
1    2012-12-20         7841      M   2012-12-01
2    2012-12-21         8374      F   2012-12-01
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is related to `get_month` because first you need to transform `Purchase_Date` to a datetime serie:

```
import datetime as dt
data.Purchase_Date = pd.to_datetime(data.Purchase_Date, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
data['Purchase_Date'].apply(get_month)

# 0   2012-12-01
# 1   2012-12-01
# 2   2012-12-01
```

You can also get the `InvoiceMonth` using [`MonthBegin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin.html) so you don't have to declare `get_month`

```
from pd.tseries.offset import MonthBegin

data.Purchase_Date = pd.to_datetime(data.Purchase_Date, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
data['InvoiceMonth'] = data.Purchase_Date - MonthBegin(1)

data['InvoiceMonth']
# 0   2012-12-01
# 1   2012-12-01
# 2   2012-12-01
```